# R: Increasing specific elements of item-person plot using package WrightMap

Tags: r

I want to plot my data within an item-person plot using the R package `WrightMap`, just like in this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JusJP.png).

Unfortunately, the font size of labels outlined with a red box on the right is too small. The same applies to the thickness of the lines indicating the position of item labels, which are outlined with a dark red border at the bottom.

I have used this code:

```
wrightMap(person_data, item_data
, axis.items = ""
, axis.logits = ""
, label.items.cex = 1.5 # increase item labels
)
```

It successfully increases the font size of labels of the items. As you can see, you can address the horizontal axis via `items` and the vertical axis via `logits`. However, when I add `label.logits.cex = 1.5` to this code, the vertical axis labels are not increased in size.

Is there a way to increase the font size of the vertical axis and the thickness of the lines on the horizontal axis?

Thank you very much for your help!